# How to Set page to start after filtering.?

Tags: ng2-smart-table

In my ng2-smart-table, I am using built-in column filters to filter the data. I always want to set the page to first, whenever the data is filtered. for example when the data is loaded in the table and I navigate to page 10 and search using an in-built column filter. I want to see the results from the first page instead of the Last page. How can I implement it? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

i did it with the following code:

```
ResetTable () {
    this.source.reset(true); 
    this.source.setPage(1, false);

    let filterArr = this.getFilterArray(); // customer method to update my filter 
     if (filterArr.length)
       this.source.setFilter(filterArr, false, false); // set the new filter 

    this.source.refresh(); 
}
```